# How to debug MacOS SystemUIServer

Tags: macos, wireless-networking

I'm using 10.14.4

Recently, when I click Wifi icon at the top bar, it could freeze the top bar, and I found the process SystemUIServer not responding via Activity Monitor.app

I can kill the not responding process, when I click it again, it becomes not responding again.

I have to restart the computer.

If I open System Preference/Network, and click the Wi-fi on the left,  the com.apple.preference.network.remoteservice (System Preferences) becomes noot Responding status.

I don't know how to debug this issue, and I have tried create a new "Location", etc.